# Meteor.js: Wait for server to finish

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm running into a scenario where my meteor server call is posting to a remote URL and then returning the result. However, my meteor client is expecting a result right away and its receiving an empty string (the default return).

What is the correct way of implementing this?

```
Meteor.methods({
run: function(options){
            return HTTP.post(apiUrl, {
                    params:
                    {
                        "headers": headers
                    }
                },
                function (error, result)
                {
                    if (error)
                    {
                        console.log("error: " + error);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        console.log("result: " + JSON.stringify(result));
                        console.log(result.content);
                    }
                })
});
```

on my client

```
Meteor.call('run', '1', function(err,response) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);        
            return;
        }else{
            r = response;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(r));
            FileSystem.update({ _id: fileid }, { $set: {taskid:taskid} }, function (e, t) {
                if (e) {

                }else{

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

I'm expecting on the client side that it waits for the full result to come in which contains the desired data to save to data base (taskid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `HTTP.post` asynchronously. Just remove the callback function and it becomes synchronous, i.e., you will get a return value that contains the result of the call:

```
Meteor.methods({
    run: function(options){
        return HTTP.post(apiUrl, {
            params:
            {
                "headers": headers
            }
        });
    });
});
```